# Create a batch file to rename copy then delete files

Tags: batch-file

I have created a .BAT file to copy all files from one directory to a couple of different ones.

```bash
@ECHO OFF

copy M:\1101\Tipo\NT K:\
copy M:\1101\Tipo\NT M:\1101\Tipo

PAUSE
```

I would like to rename all of these files before copying them. The names will come from specific text within each file, (.CAM files). The text I'm after, is part of the content on line 5, (when viewed in notepad). It always starts with `W2`, followed by some random numbers, and ends in `504`.

Here is an image showing the contents of two files, (to give you an idea):

[image: CAM files]

Comment: the exact format of the text file is important, especially the fifth line. Can you show an example (or multiple, if the format changes) You say "starts with "W2" **or** ends in "504"" Is that correct, or should it say "and"?  Is this string the only content of this line (see first question)?

Comment: Thanks @Stephan - Was meant to say that it always starts with W2 and ends with 504 and its not the only content in the search string. I have edited my original post to reflect that and have added a picture as well :)

Comment: Should make it easy. Is it the only line starting with `COM_NAM:`?

Comment: @Stephan it sure is!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a `for` loop to iterate over your source files, use another `for /f` loop to extract the new name, copy it to two destinations using the new name and delete the original:

```
@echo off
pushd "M:\1101\Tipo\NT"
for %%f in (pc2_*.cam) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /b "COM_NAM:" "%%f"') do (
    ECHO copy "%%f" "D:\est\%%a.cam"
    ECHO copy "%%f" "O:\ther\Dest\%%a.cam"
    ECHO del "%%f"
  )
)
```

Remove the `ECHO`s (failsafe) after verifying that it does what you want. And have a backup of your data - just in case.

Comment: Absolute Legend! thanks for your help :) it definitely worked!!

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

rem The following settings for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir1=u:\your results\1"
SET "destdir2=u:\your results\two"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.cam" '
 ) DO CALL :subproc "%sourcedir%\%%e"
 rem %%e has filename only
)

GOTO :EOF

:subproc
SET "newname="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%q IN ('type %1') DO IF "%%q"=="COM_NAM" SET "newname=%%r"
:testname
IF NOT DEFINED newname GOTO complain
:: Remove any leading characters from newname until the first two are "W2"
IF "%newname:~0,2%" neq "W2" SET "newname=%newname:~1%"&goto testname
:: Remove any trailing characters from newname until the last four are "-504"
IF "%newname:~-4%" neq "-504" SET "newname=%newname:~0,-1%"&goto testname
ECHO REN "%~1" "%newname%.cam"
ECHO COPY "%sourcedir%\%newname%.cam" "%destdir1%\"
ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%newname%.cam" "%destdir2%\"

GOTO :eof

:complain
ECHO %1 does NOT contain "COM_NAM:?*W2?*-504"
GOTO :eof
```

**Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.**

The `for/f %%e` assigns each filename produced by the `dir` subcommand to `%%e`, and then the subprocedure `subproc` is executed, passing that filename, with the directoryname affixed and quoted.

The subprocedure reads the file and tokenises each line, assigning the first token on each line to `%%q` and the remainder of the line after the delimiter `:` to `%%r` (see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation - or there are many examples on SO)....and thence to `newname`.

If `newname` has been set, look at the first 2 characters and delete the first character if the first 2 are not "W2"

Repeat for the last 4 characters until they become "-504"

Now we have either removed all characters from `newname` (so we complain) or we have the string between `W2` and `-504` required as the new name.

Rename the file, copy the newly-named file to the first directory, then move the file to the second so it doesn't need to be deleted.

**Note** The rename, copy and move commands are merely `echo`ed for verification. Once they are checked as being correct, remove the `echo` keyword to activate.